# Laravel5.1 で php artisan serve 時にエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer

Laravel の導入時のエラーについての質問です。

OS は CentOS 6.7、 PHP は 5.6.24 です。

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test
```

で作成した test ディレクトリに入り、

```
cd test
chmod -R a+w storage/*
chmod -R a+w bootstrap/cache
php artisan key:generate
```

をした後、

```
php artisan serve
```

を実行すると

> PHP Warning:        require(/home/vagrant/test/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/test/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/vagrant/test/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/vagrant/test/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

というエラーが出ます。

調べてみたところ、

```
composer install
```

または

```
composer update
```

をやると解消するということを見つけてやってみましたが、状況が変わりません。

vendor ディレクトリがもともとないのがそもそもの問題と考えていますが、 `composer install` で生成されるものではないのでしょうか？

対処法をご存知のかたいらっしゃいましたら、アドバイスいただければ嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 仰る通り、vendorディレクトリは `composer install` や `composer update` で生成するものです。`composer install` 時に何かエラーが出ていませんか？（そもそも `composer` がグローバルにインストールされていないとか）

Comment: 仰るとおり`composer install`の際に、php-xmlがないというエラーが出ていました。
php-xmlをインストールしたところ、このエラーは解消しました。

コメントありがとうございます。返事が遅くなり、申し訳ございませんでした。